# JamboPay and Rails Integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have JamboPay api that i want to integrate with my rails application. It looks something like this;

```
<form method="post" action="https://www.jambopay.com/JPExpress.aspx" target="_blank">
<input type="hidden" name="jp_item_type" value="cart"/>
<input type="hidden" name="jp_item_name" value="test shop"/>
<input type="hidden" name="order_id" value="455879"/>
<input type="hidden" name="jp_business" value="business@yourdomain.com"/>
<input type="hidden" name="jp_amount_1" value="51"/>
<input type="hidden" name="jp_amount_2" value="0"/>
<input type="hidden" name="jp_amount_5" value="0"/>
<input type="hidden" name="jp_payee" value="email@yourcustomer.com"/>
<input type="hidden" name="jp_shipping" value="company name"/>
<input type="hidden" name="jp_rurl" value="http://www.yourwebsite.com/testpost/Result.aspx?ii=0"/>
<input type="hidden" name="jp_furl" value="http://www.yourwebsite.com/testpost/Result.aspx?ii=1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="jp_curl" value="http://www.yourwebsite.com/testpost/Result.aspx?ii=2"/>
<input type="image" src="https://www.jambopay.com/jambohelp/jambo/rsc/paymentsbyJamboPay.jpg"/>
</form>
```

I want to be able to send this information from my transactions controller in the create method.

Any ideas how i can pass this form from my controllers because i keep the same form for all payment methods in the views.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can send this post request using Net::HTTP library all you have to do is to send this information to your controller action and then send post request from action.

Comment: How about this `<input type="image" src="https://www.jambopay.com/jambohelp/jambo/rsc/paymentsbyJamboPay.jpg"/>`